# Does almost sure convergence and finite supremum of $E |X_n|^p$ imply finite $E|X_n|$?

Tags: probability

If $X_n \rightarrow X$ almost surely and $E|X_n|^p$ has finite supremum, what does that tell us about convergence of $E|X_n|^p$ towards $E|X|^p$, or even just existence/finiteness of $E|X|^p$?

Comment: If $p > 1$, then $E|Y|^p < \infty$ always implies $E|Y| < \infty$.  Are you asking about whether we have $E|X_n| \to E|X|$?

Comment: Sorry, edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have almost sure convergence and $\sup E[|X_n|^p] <\infty$, then Fatou's lemma shows that $E|X|^p < \infty$, since we can use $$E[|X|^p] = E[\liminf |X_n|^p] \leq \liminf E[|X_n|^p] \leq \sup E[|X_n|^p] < \infty.$$

However, we don't necessarily have convergence of the means.  For instance, consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and set $X_n = n \mathbf{1}_{[0,1/n]}$.  Then $X_n \to 0 = X$ almost surely, but $E[X_n] = 1$ for all $1$.